# Function only working one time and then stops working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can someone tell me what is wrong in this function? It's a button that changes between different displays everytime you click (different questions to be exact) but it only works the first one and then is not working anymore. Any ideas? Do i have to put the variable inside the function? I am not sure if the conflict it's in the ++cont or cont++.

```
let cont = 0;

  $('.boton_pregunta'+cont).click(function(){
    $('#pregunta'+cont).fadeOut(1000);
    ++cont;
    setTimeout(function(){ $('#pregunta'+cont).fadeIn(1000); }, 1000);
  });
```

Comment: Think about how many times you call `$('.boton_pregunta'+cont).click` and with what values of `cont`.

Comment: `cont++;` and `++cont;` as statements on their own are the same.

Comment: Would be helpful to include some of your HTML - see [mcve].   If your code worked, you would have a single element with `class='boton_pregunta0'` and multiple elements with`id=pregunta0`/`id=pregunta1` etc.  I'm guessing that's *not* what you have.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one `click` event handler registered on `$('.boton_pregunta0')`. If you fade in the second part, there is no click handler yet.

You can solve this by adding it as part as the click handler of the former event.

```
let cont = 0;

function handleClick() {
  // [optional] disable click event current button
  $('.boton_pregunta'+cont).off("click");
  $('#pregunta'+cont).fadeOut(1000);

  ++cont;

  // enable click event of the revealed button
  $('.boton_pregunta'+cont).click(handleClick);
  setTimeout(function(){ $('#pregunta'+cont).fadeIn(1000); }, 1000);
}

$('.boton_pregunta'+cont).click(handleClick);
```

Comment: Likely correct, but speculative.  The click is on boton_pregunta and the fade is on `#pregunta` - there's no defined relation between these and a *single* boton could be outside the multiple pregunta.  OP needs to clarify their HTML.